# Radio button not checked the second time

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have a set of questions is survey based application each page have one question with answer and previous,next button.
When i checked the first time it was working fine. If user modify the answer when they click prev or next button clicked previous value not checked in the radio button.

my code is below

**HTML**

```
    <div id="survey-screen" data-role="page">
   <div class="header-bgcolor" data-role="header">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>
               <a href="#">
               <img src="images/teleperformance-logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="536" height="109">
               </a>
            </h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="innerContainer" data-role="main">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div class="login select-location">
            <div class="divs">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group center-button">
               <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="next">Next</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group center-button">
               <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="prev">Prev</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group center-button">
               <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="sub">submit</a>
            </div>
            <!--<a id="next" style="background-color:#fff;color:#000;padding:3px;">next</a>
               <a id="prev" style="background-color:#fff;color:#000;padding:3px;">prev</a>-->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $("#next").on('click', function(){

    $('#prev').show();
   // alert($('.divs').html());
    var id = $(".divs div:visible").attr("id");
    var last_id = $('.divs').children().last().attr('id');
    var nxt_id = +id + +1;
    var id1 = "#" + id + " input[type='radio']:checked";
    alert($("#"+nxt_id+" input[type='radio']").is(':checked') + "Next Value" );
    var value = $(id1).val();

    //alert(value);
    if(value == null || value == '' || value ==undefined ) {
        value = 'no answer';
    }
    //alert(value + "second");
    var myObj = {};
    myObj["question"] = $('#label-'+id).text();
    myObj["value"] = value;
    myObj["notes"] = $('#textarea-' + id).val();

    var result = {value:value,notes:value};
    map[id] = myObj
    for (var i in map) {
        //alert(i);
        //alert(map[i]);
    }
    if(nxt_id == last_id) {
       $('#next').hide();
    }

    if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0)

        $(".divs > div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").hide();

        $(".divs > div:first").show();

    }

    $('.divs div.ui-radio').css("display","block");

    $('.divs div.select-checkbox').css("display","block");

    $('.divs div.select-textarea').css("display","block");

    return false;

 });


$("#prev").on('click', function(){
    $('#next').show();
     //alert($('.divs').html());
    var id = $(".divs div:visible").attr("id");
    var value = $("#"+id+" input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    var first_id = $('.divs').children().first().attr('id');
    var pre_id = id-1;
    alert($("#"+pre_id+" input[type='radio']").is(':checked') );
    if(value == null || value == '' || value ==undefined) {
        value = 'no answer';
    }

    var myObj = {};
    myObj["question"] = $('#label-'+id).text();
    myObj["value"] = value;
    myObj["notes"] = $('#textarea-' + id).val();
    map[id] = myObj;

    var preValue = map[pre_id].value;
    alert(preValue + " = " + pre_id);

    //$("input[id=radio-" + pre_id + "][value='" + preValue + "']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
    //for (var i in map) {
      //  alert(i);
        //alert(map[i]);
    //}
    if(pre_id == first_id) {
       $('#prev').hide(); 
    }
    if ($(".divs > div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
        $(".divs > div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    } else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs > div:last").show();
    }
    var chk_id = "#"+pre_id+" input:radio[value=" + preValue + "]:first";
    alert(chk_id);
    $(chk_id).attr("checked", "checked");
    $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
    $('.divs div.ui-radio').css("display","block");
    $('.divs div.select-textarea').css("display","block");
    $('.divs div.select-checkbox').css("display","block");
    return false;
});

$(".checkbox").on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checked')
});
```

how to achieve that?

Comment: can u post the whole code including html

Comment: "value not checked in the radio button" , you missed some words ? I don't understand

Comment: @Zl3n I'm trying to check the value what user previously selected by clicking the previous button.

Comment: @Ben10 If your code in one-page, you should retrieve the checked checkboxes ...

Comment: @Zl3n yes, My code in one page. Here what I do. can you post code snippets

Comment: @ankitchaudhary I updated my question.

Comment: it seems your html view is dynamic because in your posted code we didn't see any checkbox

Comment: Indeed, where are the input[type="checkbox"] ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `attr()` to (un)check a checkbox.

Please use [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

```
$(chk_id).prop("checked", true);
```

Further information about [how to use `prop()` with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/2321643) are already on stackoverflow.com.